# Visual Basic Connection To MySQL Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, basic

This is my code the system believes that the ByVal Syntax No longer existis. It worked in Visual Studio 2005 but I upgraded to Visual Studio 2010 and cant find a syntax to replace it. The error is in the 2nd Line.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TestConnection()
End Sub

Public Sub TestConnection()
    Try
        Dim connStr As String = "Database=world;" & _
                "Data Source=192.168.125.21;" & _
                "User Id=worldUser;Password=worldpassword"
        Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
        connection.Open()
        connection.Close()
        MsgBox("Connection is okay.")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why that isn't working.  It looks fine to me.  But if it's any consolation, you really don't need the ByVal. You can just say `Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load`.  In fact, when you create a new on_load handler in VS (I'm using 2013), that's what it'll give you.  Did you try recreating the form load event from VS 2010?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the reference (`mysql.data.dll`) to the project, then add the import and the public class

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        TestConnection()
    End Sub

    Public Sub TestConnection()
        Try
            Dim connStr As String = "Database=database;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root"
            Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
            connection.Open()
            connection.Close()
            MsgBox("Connection is okay.")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```